# Limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x-c}\right)^x$

Tags: limits

I know that,

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x-c}\right)^x = e^c$

However I am really struggling to prove it. Could anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction to find a proof?

Comment: What is your definition of the number $e$? Do you know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-\frac{c}{x})^x=e^{-c}$? If yes then all you have to do is use simple arithmetic of limits.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$(\frac{x}{x-c})^x=\frac{1}{(1-\frac{c}{x})^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\left(\frac{x}{x-c}\right)^x=\exp\left(-x\log\left(1-\frac{c}x\right)\right)$$
And:
$$\log\left(1-\frac{c}x\right)=-\frac{c}x+o\left(\frac1x\right)$$